# Rspec error "undefined method " for new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rspec, undefined

I created a model named `SponsoredPost` with `title:string, body:text and price:integer` attributes.
This new model is suppose to be a child of a `Topic` model I have.
Here is the Rspec for it:

```
RSpec.describe SponsoredPost, type: :model do
  let(:topic) {Topic.create!(name: RandomData.random_sentence,description: RandomData.random_paragraph)}
  let(:sponsored_post) { topic.sponsored_posts.create!(title: RandomData.random_sentence, body: RandomData.random_paragraph, price: 99) }
  it { should belong_to(:topic) }

  describe "attributes" do

    it "should respond  to title" do
      expect(sponsored_post).to respond_to(:title)
    end
    it "should respond to body" do
      expect(sponsored_post).to respond_to(:body)
    end
    it "should respond to price" do
      expect(sponsored_post).to respond_to(:price)
    end
  end
end
```

SponsoredPost Model :

```
class SponsoredPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

Topic Model :

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :sponsored_posts
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sponsored_posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

3 out of the 4 tests fail with an error :

```
 undefined method `sponsored_posts' for #<Topic:0x007fde82176570>
```

What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: `class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :sponsered_posts
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sponsered_posts, dependent: :destroy
end`

Comment: Typo - `sponsered_posts` in the model. Change it to `sponsored_posts`

Comment: fixed it already still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method `sponsored_posts' for Topic:0x007fde82176570

You should set the ***association*** on the `Topic` model too

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sponsored_posts
end
```

***Update:***

You have a typo in the `Topic` model, If you look closely you have defined it as `sponsered_posts` where it should be `sponsored_posts`

Comment: I did i just forgot to put it on here sorry.

Comment: Fix it but I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: where you fixed it? and try restarting the server also

Comment: Fixed the issue with the `sponsered_posts` to `sponsored_posts` in the `Topic` model .

Comment: Thank you this actually ended up working i just accidently forgot to fix one of the `sponsored_posts` but now everything is working find thank you :)

Comment: @MiguelAngelQuintana Great! Please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define inverse relation in `Topic` model as well.

```
has_many :sponsored_posts
```

Comment: I did i just forgot to put it on here sorry.